# Was voldemort's body going to die?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

Voldemort has gained "immortality" via his horcruxes, but was his body immortal to age? Looking at all the questions about Voldemort and his horcruxes what was his plan to keep his body alive. We know his first Horcux was created at age 16, yet we see him age still so it seems like eventually his body would die of old age and his soul would be left in the half dead state he was in after his spell rebounded off Harry. What was his plan here, why would he not want something such as the elixir of life to keep his vitality?

> While the Elixir of Life does indeed extend life, it must be drunk regularly, for all eternity, if the drinker is to maintain his immortality. Therefore, Voldemort would be entirely dependent on the Elixir, and if it ran out, or was contaminated, or if the Stone was stolen, he would die just like any other man. Thereafter, I am convinced, he intended to continue to rely on his Horcruxes: he would need nothing more, if only he could regain a human form. He was already immortal, you see ... or as close to immortal as any man can be.' (Albus Dumbledore)

Horcruxes seem to fail at something important, keeping you alive, they stop you from dying truly yes, but they don't keep you alive. Harry is shown over and over again to be able to beat better wizards because hes has faster reflexes both because of youth and his genetics, but presumably by 50 harry will not be as fast as his 16 year old self even considering their longer life expectancy. Why operate in a body of a 50 year old?

Comment: Where do we see Voldemort age?

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56942/did-voldemort-expect-to-live-forever-and-if-so-how) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31155/could-voldemort-have-died-a-natural-death-with-his-horcruxes-intact)

Comment: @ibid - oh. Sorry. I read your question as "age==nown", not verb. Ignore me :)

Answer (score 9):

This does not seem to be covered in canon, however, that was not really a concern for him **yet**. We see wizards survive well into their second century - Dumbledore died at 115 from **external causes**, not aging.

Tom Riddle was only 55 when he got HarryPottered, so he had about half a century to start worrying about age related preservation.

Please note that wizarding medicine seems far more advanced that Muggle, and presumably Voldemort would be able to access the best of it, without petty ethical restrictions that Dumbledore was subject to.

Please note that your question states something which is not really correct: Harry didn't beat better wizards because of his **youth** (exibit A: Neville Longbottom). He beat them because he was born with excellent genetics granting him awsome hand eye coordination, speed, and reaction, inherited from his Seeker father.

Comment: my point on his reflexes was that even with better genetics, by 50 he probably would not have been as fast as he was at 16. and i presume that Voldemort could have started to have some of the same limitations at 50, even if in reality he was closer to his 20s-30s in actual life lived/ life expectancy.

Comment: @Himarm - no canon info for or against that